# How NodeJS server running for ever

Tags: node.js, centos

I use Putty.
When I start server with "node X.js", putty start server running.
If I exit from putty the server stop.
How I can keep it running and make it default running after restart or reboot the server (computer)?

I have centos 5.10.
Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I use pm2 to do it

To install pm2

```
sudo npm install -g pm2
```

To generate startup script

```
pm2 startup ubuntu(centos in your case)
```

Then pm2 will prompt the command for you to run, in my case, it is like

```
PM2 You have to run this command as root
PM2 Execute the following command :
PM2 sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u USERNAME
```

Then you could run

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin pm2 startup ubuntu -u USERNAME
```

Then you could see

```
PM2 Generating system init script in /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh
PM2 Making script booting at startup...
PM2 -ubuntu- Using the command su -c "chmod +x /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh && update-rc.d pm2-init.sh defaults"
Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc1.d/K20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc6.d/K20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc2.d/S20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc3.d/S20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc4.d/S20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh
   /etc/rc5.d/S20pm2-init.sh -> ../init.d/pm2-init.sh

PM2 Done.
```

Once you have started the apps and want to keep them on server reboot do:

```
 pm2 save
```

You can refer to Startup script section in https://github.com/Unitech/pm2#startup-script

Comment: Is the apps list automatically updated or is the `pm2 save` call required?

Comment: pm2 save will have PM2 save the processes. It will restart these when the system boots back up.

Comment: I mean, when I start a new process, is the list automatically saved?

Comment: Yes, it is saved automatically after first pm2 save run

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, I personally like forever.

```
sudo npm install -g forever
forever start app.js &
```

note that ending with & will fork the process to background.

You can later check the process with

```
forever list
```

To run it when your system restarts you can add to cron

```
@reboot forever start app.js  &> /dev/null
```

Remember to point to the absolute location of app.js

Comment: If my computer reboot, forever will start the NodeJS server automatically? Thanks!

Comment: yes. Forever will create two processes. One to literally run "node app.js" and a second one in charge to monitor the first one and relaunch if needed

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about a reboot though. Because in that scenario both processes are dead.

Comment: Forever will run itself after each reboot. That's what the @reboot entry in the cron does.